# Query correcto en MongoDB

Tags: sql, nodejs, mongodb

Estoy organizando un reporte de unos vehículos extrayendo la info de una tabla que tiene estos campos ID de vehículo, velocidad, fecha. En esta tabla queda registrada la velocidad de los vehículos en cada momento.

ID_vehiculo Velocidad   Fecha
123         0           2022-10-09 08:40:32
123         70          2022-10-09 08:40:32
1234        90          2022-10-09 08:40:32

Necesito hacer un query en mongo que extraiga todas las velocidades por encima de una velocidad dada y una duración dada de uno o varios vehículos y que diga la fecha inicial y la fecha final filtrados por un rango de tiempo.

ID_vehiculo       Velocidad  Fecha Inicio.           Fecha Fin.            Duracion
123               72         2022-10-09 08:40:32.    2022-10-09 08:40:32.  00:03
123               78         2022-10-09 08:40:32.    2022-10-09 08:40:32   00:0
1234              90         2022-10-09 08:40:32.    2022-10-09 08:40:32   00:03

Son un tanto novato con mongo y hasta ahora solo he hecho esto.

```
let filter = {
            id : parseInt(id),
            speed : {
                $gt : parseInt(speed)
            }
        }

        if(date_from != null){
            filter.date_created = { 
                $gte : new Date(moment(date_from).toISOString()),
                $lt : new Date(moment(date_to).toISOString())
            }
        }else{
            filter.date_created = { 
                $gte : new Date(moment().subtract(1, "month").toISOString()),
                $lt : new Date(moment().toISOString())
            }
        }
        try {
            const [DB] = await this.Mongodb.onConnect();
            DB.collection('vehicles').find(
                filter,
                {
                    "id" : "$id",
                    "speed" : "$speed",
                    "date_created" : "$date_created",
                })
                .sort(
                    {
                        "id" : 1
                    }
                )
                .toArray( (error, rsDT) => {
                DB.close();
                if( error ){
                    reject(error);
                }else{
                    result(null,rsDT);
                    resolve(rsDT);  
                }
            });
```

Comment: Estas trabajando directamente con mongo? No te sería más fácil utilizar mongoose? No se que tan avanzado tengas el proyecto

Comment: ¿Porqué dices que tienes una **tabla**? En MongoDB no existe tal cosa, en cambio existen colecciones. No mezcles conceptos.

Comment: @Legna me lo entregaron asi y esta algo adelantado. Lo que hago ahora es que uso un manejador de base de datos, escribo consultas sql y me las convierte a consultas de mongo.

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias por la corrección. Disculpa es que soy nuevo con mongo y confundo algunos términos con SQL.

Comment: @BPolanco, pareciese que el dato de la velocidad es un string, no te da algún error? Puedes corroborar que verdaderamente se está guardando como número?

Comment: @Legna es un numero, ya lo comprobe, de hecho ya he probado sacando la velocidad mayor, la menor y la http://10.0.0.106:40002/ y todo bien.